# copy, move then rename file in php

Tags: php

I am working on the member registration section of my site and when a member registers it creates a folder in images/useravatars/(username) but in folder images/useravatars/ there is a 001.png file which I want to copy, rename (to the users name) and paste to the new members newly created folder. How is this done in php? It is a default avatar image which gets assigned to all newly registered members.

Comment: Did you tried anything yet ? Do you have any code to share ?

Comment: the copy() function comes to mind

Comment: this is as far as i got:   //create user avatar folder and put avatar into it
  $dir = $_POST['username'];
    
  if( is_dir("images/profilephotos/user-avatars/" . $dir) === false )
  { 
  $oldmask = umask(0);
  mkdir("images/profilephotos/user-avatars/" . $dir, 0777);
  umask($oldmask);
  }else{
   // do error folder already exists
   
  }

Comment: You can use move_uploaded_file of php

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function.

```
bool copy ( string $source , string $dest [, resource $context ] )
```

Basically what you want to do is a single step, you provide the path of the `001.png` file and then use `copy(defaultImgPath, newUserImgPath);`

Comment: Are you sure?  It lists (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7) in the manual, and I don't see any mention of the word deprecated.

Comment: Oh. Sorry for that. I thought this was deprecated in the newest version of php.

Comment: why would something like copy ever be deprecated?